# Counter example to theorem about non homogeneous and homogeneous conics in characteristic 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $K$ be a field of characteristic different from $2$ and let $a,b\in K\backslash\{0\}$. Then the equation $ax^2+by^2 = 1$ has a solution over $K$ if and only if the homogeneous equation $ax^2+by^2=z^2$ has a non-trivial solution over $K$.

I would like to find a counter example to this theorem when the characteristic of $K$ does equal $2$.

If over a field $K$ there exists a solution to $ax^2+by^2=1$, then we will automatically have a non-trivial solution for the homogeneous case. Also if there exists a non-trivial solution to $ax^2+by^2=z^2$ where $z\neq 1$, we will have a solution for $ax^2+by^2=1$. This means that finding a counter example consists of finding an appropriate field $K$ with $\operatorname{Char}(K) = 2$, such that there are $a,b\in K\backslash\{0\}$ for which $ax^2+by^2=0$ for some $x,y\in K$, but $ax^2+by^2\neq 1$ for all $x,y\in K$.

I have found that if $K$ is a finite field, there will always exist $x,y$ such that $ax^2+by^2=1$. Therefore $K$ necessarily has to be infinite, but I am not that familiar with infinite fields of characteristic $2$ nor able to show that these fields are a counter example in general.